# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'>> when retrieving tweets

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup, tweets

I have a file that includes number of user id's and tweet id's. Im trying to retrieve the the tweets using these information.
I'm having an issue when I try to retrieve the tweets. The python script is crashed when finds suspended account by twitter. The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'
```

since I'm still new in Python-land, I'm not sure how to handle this issue. I would like the script to continue retrieving the tweets even if it finds any suspended account.

an example of suspended account is the   [following](https://twitter.com/2452614538/status/451013459766173697)

example of tweets that is   [retrieved successfully](https://twitter.com/169403434/status/426559582895230976)

The code I'm using to retrieve the tweets is the following:

```
def get_tweet(user_id, tweet_id):  
"""fetch the tweet from given user_id and tweet_id  
   returns tweet text  if found, otherwise returns Not Found
"""
url = TWITTER_URL + user_id + "/status/" + tweet_id
url = url.replace("\n", "")
print(url);
tweet = 'Not Found'
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    #extrat the paragraph that contains the tweet


    tweet_paragrapgh = soup.find("div", 'original-tweet',{"data-user-id": user_id, "data-tweet-id": tweet_id}).findNext('p','js-tweet-text')
                                                                                                #strip off the html tag and get the tweet text
    #print(tweet_paragrapgh);
    tweet = tweet_paragrapgh.text
    print (tweet);
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print
    print "HTTP ERROR response code ", e.code, " for user id: ", user_id, " tweet id: ", tweet_id
    return tweet
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print
    print'Error reaching to server for ', "user id: ", user_id, " tweet id: ", tweet_id
    print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    return tweet
return tweet
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Is there anything that can be improved in the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue has not been solved yet. However,I used tweepy instead..

Answer (score 1):

Parsing twitter pages via `urllib2`+`BeautifulSoup` is really painful since there are a lot of dynamic javascript logic, `AJAX` calls involved in constructing the page.

To be specific, the page you are actually getting using `urllib2` doesn't contain `original-tweet`, there is no element with `data-tweet-id` attribute, all of the `data-user-id` attributes are empty.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use [`Twitter API`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

There are multiple python twitter API clients to choose from:

- [`python-twitter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter)
- [`twitter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter)
- [`tweepy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy)

Hope that helps.